# Understanding DXF file format. Relation between Label and Geometry

Tags: python, dxf

I'm very new to CAD system and trying to extract information from dxf file for my project. I have dxf files for floor plan. My aim is to extract geometries for the room and label associated with it.

Though i was able to extract room geometries and room labels separately, but i'm finding it hard to map the both. Is there a tag that i've missed that has link between geometry and labels?

***Room Label:***

```
0

INSERT

5

53CF

330

2

100

AcDbEntity

8

__X_Polyline_Data

100

AcDbBlockReference

66

 1
2

ROOM_DATA

10

11.15367175915704

20

10.40315868785525

30

0.0

1001

AEC_XDATA_BOUND_SPACE

1070

100

1070

 1
0

ATTRIB

5

53D1

330

53CF

100

AcDbEntity

8

__X_Polyline_Data

6

Continuous

100

AcDbText

10

11.12027175915704

20

10.44215868785524

30

0.0

40

0.25

1

AE.22

100

AcDbAttribute

280

 0
2

PART_AOID

70

 0
280

 1
```

***Room Text :***

```
0

TEXT

5

62C

330

2

100

AcDbEntity

8

X_Raumnummer

370

 0
100

AcDbText

10

11.15367175915704

20

10.40315868785525

30

0.0

40

0.8

1

AE.22
```

***Room Coordinates :***

```
0

LWPOLYLINE

5

239B

330

2

100

AcDbEntity

8

A_DEC_Durchbrüche

370

 0
100

AcDbPolyline

90

    4
70

 1
43

0.0

10

10.95

20

12.215

10

14.6

20

12.215

10

14.6

20

12.48499999999999

10

10.95

20

12.48499999999999
```

Code that i've written to extract the data:

```
lines = [entity for entity in dwg.entities if entity.dxftype == 'LWPOLYLINE']
room_lines = [entity for entity in lines if entity.layer == '__X_Polyline']
lines_data = [entity for entity in dwg.entities if entity.dxftype == 'TEXT']
room_text = [entity for entity in lines_data if entity.layer == 'X_Raumnummer']
```

I've used dxfgrabber library to extract information.

I'm sorry if my question is stupid, I'm not able to find the link and i'm fairly new to this field. I was able to extract AE.22 and it's 4 coordinates, but now able to map them together.

Comment: Do you really need blank lines between every line or two? It makes it hard to read the data.

Answer (score 2):

What you are attempting to do is not really how most 2D drafting works.

Imagine a blank sheet of paper.  You pick up a pencil and draw a square.  You decide that this will be a room.  So somewhere near the square that you have drawn, you write some text; "Room 1" for instance.  There is no intrinsic relationship or 'link' between the text "Room 1" and the square you have drawn.  These are completely disconnected entities.  The relationship only exists in the mind of the drafter, or if the text and square are close together, a relationship might be inferred by someone else viewing the drawing.

This is exactly how the vast majority of 2D drafting (.dxf files) works also.  Unless you set up special objects with attributes, there is no relationship between any piece of text and any other drawing entity in a .dxf file.

If you happen to have drawings where the room label is always placed 'inside' the room, then you can do some math to determine if a particular piece of text lies within a specific set of lines/polylines.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I understood it way better now. Thank you.